# I can't install python dlib through anaconda

Tags: installation, anaconda, dlib, python-3.9

```
(base) PS C:\dlib-19.23> cd c:\Users\Donggue
(base) PS C:\Users\Donggue> pip install opencv-contrib-python dlib
Collecting opencv-contrib-python
  Using cached opencv_contrib_python-4.5.5.64-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl (42.2 MB)
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.23.1.tar.gz (7.4 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.19.3 in c:\users\donggue\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from opencv-contrib-python) (1.20.3)
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error


  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1

...

(base) PS C:\dlib-19.23> cd c:\Users\Donggue
(base) PS C:\Users\Donggue> pip install opencv-contrib-python dlib
Collecting opencv-contrib-python
  Using cached opencv_contrib_python-4.5.5.64-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl (42.2 MB)
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.23.1.tar.gz (7.4 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.19.3 in c:\users\donggue\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from opencv-contrib-python) (1.20.3)
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1

...

 subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--config', 'Release', '--', '/m']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> dlib

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I'm trying to install dlib using anaconda.
I enter `pip install dlib` and `conda` for installing dilb on anaconda prompt. and I also installed cmake. my python verison is 3.9.7.
I also download dlib at dlib.net. and enter "py setup.py build" and "py setup.py install"

Comment: You mentioned that you ahve tried to run `conda` for the installation. Have you tried to install both with `conda`? `conda install -c conda-forge dlib py-opencv` What is the error you get there? Please add it to your question

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed Cmake already? If not, try running `conda install -c anaconda cmake`

And after that `conda install -c conda-forge dlib`